# Android Chrome multiline text-shadow rendering with blur

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, blur

I experienced a weird bug in Android´s (6.0.1) Chrome Browser (54.0.2840.68) when it comes to text-shadow rendering with large fontsizes and blur. It was also reported to appear in MacOS Chrome although i could not reproduce it.

I condensed the problem into a small pen for further investigation:
http://codepen.io/quarkus/pen/BQaBGj

This is, in short the styled headline i am trying to render.

```
h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  line-height: 1.2; 
}

h1.shadow {
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent, 0px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); 
}
```

The classes .filter, .fix3d and .fix are just attempts to fix this problem by rendering the headlines in a 3d context (or by creating the shadow as a blurred :before).

This is how it looks an most android devices:

[s.codepen.io/quarkus/debug/BQaBGj on the device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymnEt.png)

Has anyone ever experienced that kind of rendering and can point me to a solution ?

Thanks
Markus

EDIT: forgot one thing. it occurs only if the page is "scaled" either by the user itself or by stting an meta-tag like:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`
as it is in the pen.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem on https://businessimages.ch (right at the top). It seems to only happen on some versions of Chrome/Android as I've tested on two different devices in my office. It does happen on the latest Samsung Galaxy 7 with what is, I'm assuming, the latest version of Android. I do have the meta viewport tag set (but taking that out is not a solution in my case). Any info would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I'm definitely getting this on Browserstack devices (Galaxy and Nexus phones), I've not seen it on a device, but I don't have tons of devices to check.

However what fixed it for me was transforming and blocking the text:

```
.text {
    transform: translateZ(0);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Not an excellent fix as I need my text to `display: inline` but it works.